# Looking for an anime with only an image

Tags: story-identification, anime

I actually know little to nothing about the anime as I only saw clips on YouTube, but I do have an image.

[image: Here is a cropped image]

Answer (score 12):

Google says this image is from [*The Rolling Girls*](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt4219166/) (2015).  The image itself can be found on the page for episode 10 at [Anime News Network](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/review/the-rolling-girls/episode-10/.85978).

[My Anime List](https://myanimelist.net/anime/25867/Rolling%E2%98%86Girls) gives the following synopsis:

> In a dystopian future where Japan's political organization has crumbled after the Great Tokyo War, Japan is broken up into 10 independent nations, with each nation controlled by a gang led by a "Best," a human-proclaimed prophet with destructive superpowers. Nozomi Moritomo is a "Rest"—a normal girl that has just started out as a rookie in the local gang. She wants to help the Best Masami Utoku, her childhood friend and role model, in the ongoing territorial dispute.

Comment: Thank you so much